# Custom-sort large Json based on date and ID

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a large Json file containing data that is generated multiple times a day, in this structure:

```
[
    {
 
       "data1":19.77,
 
       "data2":-0.953125,
 
       "data3":-0.265625,
 
       "data4":0.0859375,

       "id":8,
 
       "date":"2021-05-14/09:25:47.471"
 
    },
    {
 
       "data1":19.77,
 
       "data2":-0.953125,
 
       "data3":-0.265625,
 
       "data4":0.0859375,

       "id":8,
 
       "date":"2021-05-14/08:38:47.471"
 
    },
 
    {

       "data1":19.77,
 
       "data2":-0.953125,
 
       "data3":-0.265625,
 
       "data4":0.078125,
 
       "id":8,
 
       "date":"2021-05-13/08:38:47.596"
 
    },
 
    {
 
       "data1":19.77,
 
       "data2":-0.9609375,
 
       "data3":-0.2734375,
 
       "data4":0.0859375,
 
       "id":1,
 
       "date":"2021-05-14/08:39:47.721"
 
    },
    {
 
        "data1":19.77,
  
        "data2":-0.9609375,
  
        "data3":-0.2734375,
  
        "data4":0.0859375,
  
        "id":3,
  
        "date":"2021-05-14/08:38:47.721"
  
     },
     {
 
        "data1":19.77,
  
        "data2":-0.9609375,
  
        "data3":-0.2734375,
  
        "data4":0.0859375,
  
        "id":1,
  
        "date":"2021-05-14/08:38:47.721"
  
     },
    {
 
       "data1":19.77,
 
       "data2":-0.953125,
 
       "data3":-0.265625,
 
       "data4":0.0859375,

       "id":8,
 
       "date":"2021-05-14/09:38:47.471"
 
    },]
```

What I'm having trouble with is sorting this data neatly, based on id and datetime, to look something like this:

```
list1 = [{

    "data1":19.77,

    "data2":-0.9609375,

    "data3":-0.2734375,

    "data4":0.0859375,

    "id":1,

    "date":"2021-05-14/08:38:47.721"

 },
 {

    "data1":19.77,

    "data2":-0.9609375,

    "data3":-0.2734375,

    "data4":0.0859375,

    "id":1,

    "date":"2021-05-14/08:39:47.721"

 }]
 list2 = {

    "data1":19.77,

    "data2":-0.9609375,

    "data3":-0.2734375,

    "data4":0.0859375,

    "id":3,

    "date":"2021-05-14/08:38:47.721"

 }
list3 = [{

   "data1":19.77,

   "data2":-0.953125,

   "data3":-0.265625,

   "data4":0.0859375,

   "id":8,

   "date":"2021-05-13/08:38:47.471"

},
{
 
   "data1":19.77,
 
   "data2":-0.953125,
 
   "data3":-0.265625,
 
   "data4":0.0859375,

   "id":8,
 
    "date":"2021-05-14/08:38:47.471"
 
}
{

   "data1":19.77,

   "data2":-0.953125,

   "data3":-0.265625,

   "data4":0.078125,

   "id":8,

   "date":"2021-05-14/09:25:47.596"

}]
```

I'm trying to sort this so I can upload this data to an Firestore in this schema:

```
Data
    ├───ID 1
    ├───ID 3
    └───ID 8
```

Sadly, since this json file comes from an custom-made device, I have no way to change how the data is saved to the json file.

One thing to note is that the number of ID's will never change, always 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

load the JSON file and you will get list of dicts. Then

```
spam = [
    {
 
       "data1":19.77,
 
       "data2":-0.953125,
 
       "data3":-0.265625,
 
       "data4":0.0859375,

       "id":8,
 
       "date":"2021-05-14/09:25:47.471"
 
    },
    {
 
       "data1":19.77,
 
       "data2":-0.953125,
 
       "data3":-0.265625,
 
       "data4":0.0859375,

       "id":8,
 
       "date":"2021-05-14/08:38:47.471"
 
    },
 
    {

       "data1":19.77,
 
       "data2":-0.953125,
 
       "data3":-0.265625,
 
       "data4":0.078125,
 
       "id":8,
 
       "date":"2021-05-13/08:38:47.596"
 
    },
 
    {
 
       "data1":19.77,
 
       "data2":-0.9609375,
 
       "data3":-0.2734375,
 
       "data4":0.0859375,
 
       "id":1,
 
       "date":"2021-05-14/08:39:47.721"
 
    },
    {
 
        "data1":19.77,
  
        "data2":-0.9609375,
  
        "data3":-0.2734375,
  
        "data4":0.0859375,
  
        "id":3,
  
        "date":"2021-05-14/08:38:47.721"
  
     },
     {
 
        "data1":19.77,
  
        "data2":-0.9609375,
  
        "data3":-0.2734375,
  
        "data4":0.0859375,
  
        "id":1,
  
        "date":"2021-05-14/08:38:47.721"
  
     },
    {
 
       "data1":19.77,
 
       "data2":-0.953125,
 
       "data3":-0.265625,
 
       "data4":0.0859375,

       "id":8,
 
       "date":"2021-05-14/09:38:47.471"
 
    },]

print(sorted(spam, key = lambda x: (x['id'], x['date'])))
```

or

```
spam.sort(key = lambda x: (x['id'], x['date']))
print(spam)
```

EDIT:

```
from itertools import groupby
for key, items in groupby(sorted(spam, key = lambda x: (x['id'], x['date'])), key=lambda x: x['id']):
   print(f'id:{key}')
   print(list(items))
```

Comment: That works wonders, thank you so much. 
Do you have any tips on how I can separete the list ? For example, list1 contaning all the data from ID 1, list2 from ID 8 and so on ?

Comment: look at `itertools.groupby`. I edited my answer to show an example